# Is there a verb form for how an effigy relates to its target or referent?

Tags: single-word-requests

So an inanimate object in a story is representative of a person in the story. Anything that happens to the object represents something that happens to the person. So what’s the word for “The object ____ the person”. Sort of like symbolizes, represents, but not exactly it.

Comment: It would help if you narrowed the field.  What words have you considered, and why don't they work?  *Resemble* or *evoke* come to mind, but they're different - and perhaps neither suits your purpose.

Comment: The choice of word(s) here might hinge on the time frame. If what happens to the object coincides in time with what happens to the person, *embodies* might work. But if what happens to the object precedes what happens to the person, perhaps *foreshadows* would be more appropriate, although that word is usually used with events.

Comment: It would help us if you could explain why symbolises and represents don't quite fit. Do pairs of events actually happen, one to the object and one to the person, or does something happen to the object that *allegorises* what happens to the person?

Comment: In any word or phrase request, we need: (i) your criteria for accepting answers, including the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for; (ii) exactly in what context you want to use the word or phrase – generally we want the sentence you're writing; and (iii) details of the research you've already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you've already considered but rejected, and why. For a full explanation from SE staff, see: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. (i) just essay language formality, verb (ii) "The black key __ the devil. “ would be the sentence I’m using it in. Whatever happens to the key happens to the devil. Whoever owns the key is in control of the devil. (iii) I’ve tried to use google and thesaurus.com but I’m not even sure what to find a synonym of. The first word that come to my mind was _embodied_ but the definition is "to give a concrete form to” but the person is already a tangible form. Foreshadows is too loose of a connection between the two.

Comment: Symbolises and represents don’t quite fit because the key doesn’t really symbolise and represent the devil in a sense that the devil himself exists without the key in the story and the key also doesn’t depend on the devil. I’m trying to argue that the key in the story ___ the devil and symbolizes and represents is too broad and not exactly what I want to convey.

Comment: The closest I can think of is the popular view of voodoo dolls, but that doesn't lend itself to a verb form. I don't think there is a single word to describe exactly how your key and devil are linked.

Comment: Victoria, if you could justify how the key doesn’t really symbolise or represent the devil you'd prolly be onto a winner.

Until then, why not use Google and Thesaurus.Com to find synonyms of, for instance, symbolise or represent?